# Conditional Port connectivity during module /wrapper instantiation

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, module

I have a wrapper, with multiple ports (mainly used to parameterize/scale a particular module) and in this wrapper i parameterize the module instantiation with help of generate for-loop.
i.e.

```
generate 
for (genvar a=0; a< NUM1; a++) 
begin : module_label 
module module_inst( 
.x1(x1[a]), 
.x2(x2[a]), 
.x3(x3[a]), 
.y(y[a]) 
  );
end
endgenerate
```

Now i want to control my port connectivity inside this module instantiation based on some condition. Can i use a if loop within this instantiation? Something like :

```
generate 
for (genvar a=0; a< NUM1; a++)  
begin : module_label 
module module_inst( 
.x1(x1[a]), 
if ( NUM2 = 5) begin 
.x2(x2[a]), 
.x3(x3[a]), 
end 
.y(y[a]) 
);
end
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 2):

The ports on your submodule will always exist whether you use them on not.

If you don't connect an input/inout port of a submodule it will be connected to some default value by the synthesis tool. This is usually `'b0` for an input, or `'bz` for an inout port, but could be anything. Leaving inputs unterminated is not ideal.

If you don't connect an output port of a submodule, it will be unused.

You don't however specify the definition of your submodule, so I have no idea what direction `x2` and `x3` are.

---

If `x2` is an input, you can use a ternary operator such as:

```
.x2((NUM2 == 5) ? x2[a] : otherVal),
```

Where `otherVal` is whatever value you want to drive the port when `NUM2` is not 5. This could for example be all bits as `0`, or all `z`.

---

If `x2` is an output, then you will want to move your `if` statement to outside the module instantiation:

```
if (NUM2 == 5) begin
    module module_inst( 
        .x1(x1[a]), 
        .x2(x2[a]), 
        .x3(x3[a]), 
        .y(y[a]) 
    );
end else begin
    module module_inst( 
        .x1(x1[a]),
        .y(y[a]) 
    );
end
```

That way you instantiate the module only connecting the outputs as required.

---

As a side note, your example code uses `if(NUM2 = 5)` which should read `if(NUM2 == 5)` - note the double equal for equality rather than assignment.